# Email Address not found in Database validation in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, email-validation, angular-material-6

I I am doing a email validation for required field and for invalid email address.
I want to do a validation for "if email is not found in database " after submit button click,then it should show some error message like i am displaying for required and pattern.
Below is my code.I am using Angular 6 material design.

```
             <form [formGroup]='loginForm' id="loginForm">       
             <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Email Address</mat-label>             
              <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="emailid" required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.emailid.errors && (formControl.emailid.dirty || formControl.emailid.touched)">
                <p *ngIf="formControl.emailid.errors.required">Email is required</p>
                <p *ngIf="formControl.emailid.errors.pattern">Invalid email address</p>

              </mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
              <button mat-button type="submit" (click)="login()">Login</button>
               </form>
```

Below code id for ts file.

```
               loginForm: FormGroup;
               emailId: any;
               status: any;

               ngOnInit(){
                this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                  emailid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]]
                });
               }

                get formControl() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

                 login() {
                    this.emailId = this.loginForm.controls['emailid'].value;
                        this.service.get({{ email: this.emailId}, 'url').subscribe((response) => {
                           this.result = response;
                              this.status = this.result.status;
                              if (this.status === 200) {
                                               //navigate to home page
                            } else If(this.status === 404) {
                                console.log("email not found");
                                // here i want to show this message like aboove i am showing for required and pattern field.
                            }
                     });
```

once msg displayed , then after doing backspace in email input field the error message should disappear.And how to display "email not found" message if it is not there in database.
Can anyone please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: check this link @ananya https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
this.loginForm.controls['email'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html add a event handler on your inputfield to check if it is backspace and resetForm which would remove errors on the form.

**In HTML:**

```
<input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="emailid" (keypress)="ResetForm($event)" required>
```

**After the `<mat-error>` tag:**

```
<p *ngIf="isEmailPresent">Email Address Not found</p>
```

**In your ts file,initialize** `isEmailPresent=false` and 
   in the else part where you are getting 404,`this.isEmailPresent=true;`

**In ts file:make sure you import below**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormGroup,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroupDirective,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
```

*Add formdirective as viewchild:*

```
 @ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective;
```

*In your keypressevent reset form*

```
ResetForm(event)
{
  if(event && event.keycode==8)//(keycode for backspace)
    {
       this.formGroupDirective.resetForm();
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok @Ashok I will try this. But my actual issue is how to display error message if email address not found in database.In else part where i am checking if status is 404,then it should display error message like email not found. Can you help me how to do that?

Comment: Displaying error message worked. But backspace thing didn't work. I did this using   (keyup) in input.On keyup if length of input field value is 0, then i am changing 'isEmailPresent' false. @Ashok